# Validate ISO 8601 Date/Time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, datetime

I'm working on an app that gets values from the query string. Because the value comes from the query string, I'm basically working with string values. I need to write a JavaScript function that determines if a string is a date/time in ISO-8601 format. One of my challenges is that my JavaScript code uses strict mode (i.e. `'use strict';`). Currently, I'm trying the following:

```
var isValidDateTime = function(dateString) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('/^\s*(?:[+-]\d{6}|\d{4})-(?:(\d\d-\d\d)|(W\d\d$)|(W\d\d-\d)|(\d\d\d))((T| )(\d\d(:\d\d(:\d\d(\.\d+)?)?)?)?([\+\-]\d\d(?::?\d\d)?|\s*Z)?)?$/');
  if (pattern.text(dateString) === true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I'm passing '2014-07-28T10:53:59Z' in as the `dateString` value for testing purposes. I'm guessing my regular expression is incorrect. However, I'm not sure which one to use. Does anyone know how I can validate whether a string is a valid iso-8601 date/time?

Thank you

Comment: Why not pass the string to `Date` constructor?

Comment: From my understanding, exceptions are expensive. For that reason, I want to do a check to make the code cleaner. Instead of trying to create a Date and catching an exception.  Thank you.

Comment: Also, consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) instead of regex for this.